# MongoDB How to update multiple documents based on array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Given array of objects :

```
const array = [{_id: 1, name: 'one'}, {_id: 2, name: 'two'}]
```

**How do you construct a query so that it will update name field for each document in DB where document's id equals _id in array object?**

This must be done in a single query. 
Query must use mongoDB node driver syntax.

for example:

```
// in DB : [{_id: 1, name: null, _id: 2, name: null }]
db.collection('sprints').update(....).then(...)
// after operation:
// in DB: [{_id: 1, name: "one", _id: 2, name: "two" }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried a construct like this:

```
Promise.all(array.map(entry =>
    db.collection('sprints').findOneAndUpdate({ _id: entry._id }, { name: entry.name }).save()
)).then(...);
```

its not the direct way but worked for me (in a test case)

Comment: Is this really the only way ? this will execute as many queries as elements in the array :(

Comment: In theory its the only way. Maybe there is a function for that directly but i couldnt find it in the docs. But in the end mongoose will do a single query for each entry so it doesn't matter anyway. But you re right its definitly not a clean construct

Comment: Your query might be ok for me for now ... However I have other keys on sprint objects ... and they get overwritten with object that has only _id & name ... could you modify your query, so that only name would be modified (preserving any other keys) ?

Comment: modified with `db.collection('sprints').findOneAndUpdate({ _id: new ObjectID(sprint._id) }, { $set : { name: sprint.name} })` . to preserve other keys.

Comment: will wait to see if anybody can give a single query solution, if not I'll accept your answer